# showing circle() takes zero positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, oop

showing circle() takes zero positional arguments but 3 were given. Please help
#class

```
def circle():
    
    def __init__(self,a,b,r):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.r=r
    def Area(self):
        return (3.14*self.r**2)
    
    def Perimeter(self):
        return (2*3.14*self.r)
        
    def testBelongs(self):
        d=((a**2)+((b**2)-(r**2)))**.5;
        
        if d<self.r:
            print(" lies inside circle")
        else:
            print ("Lies outside circle")

c=circle(1,2,5)

c.Perimeter()

c.Area()

c.testBelongs()
```

Comment: You wrote `def` instead of `class`.

Comment: As @user2357112supportsMonica pointed out, ```class Circle``` is needed

Comment: please accept the formatting edits provided by other authors

Comment: Also I would like to suggest you to read python naming conventions, honestly they make good looking but that is completly my opinion and optional.